# Asynchronously updated objects throw exception while being displayed in WPF lisbox

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listbox

I am currently in process of writing WPF application which updates List<> of objects from website and displays those objects in listbox. Everything works while updating those objects synchronously, problems arise when I try the same operation but every object is updated in its own thread. Here is the code that updates whole List<> asynchronously:

```
public void UpdateAll()
{
    Console.WriteLine("[Manager]Updating {0} channels", channels.Count);

    int threadCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < channels.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = i;

        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                threadCount++;
                channels[j].Update();
                threadCount--;
            }).Start();
    }

    while (threadCount != 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("[Manager]Updating complete");
}
```

After update finishes, I try to display the objects in listbox from button's OnClick event (which should be UI thread):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < manager.Channels.Count; i++)
    {
        channelBox.Items.Add(manager.Channels[i]);
    }
}
```

Application crashes, giving this exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

For the last few hours, I have been googling solution but all I found was that this exception is fired when trying to update UI from different thread. I am sure that all update threads already finished and I see no reason why this exception is being thrown. I have also tried using Dispacher.Invoke() method to update the listbox with no success, same exception. Any help?

Comment: What are those Channels? Are they dependency objects? Does the Update method create dependency objects? Can you show the definition?

Comment: You're trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread, as the error and everything on Google is telling you.  You need to not access UI elements from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Channels is the List<> of objects. I don't think I am updating UI from non-UI thread, only thing that is done on non-UI thread is updating the List<> which has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: @KubkoPiško, I was asking about the items in the list; what is their type? Is it a subclass of DependencyObject?

Comment: Items in List<> are not inheriting from anything (if that is what are you asking). Also note that when I remove the 'new Thread(..).Start();' and just use 'channels[j].Update();' synchronously, application is doing what it is supposed to do without throwing exceptions.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the Update method, but without seeing more code, it's hard to tell for sure...

Comment: You are correct, problem was there. Your comments pushed me in right direction, many thanks!

Comment: @KubkoPiško If you've found the answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Yeah and deleting my edit was perfectly reasonable, I am not writing it again as a answer when I could just cut and paste it, many thanks for the delete! :)

Answer (score -1):

There are potentially many ways to skin this cat...perhaps you can get started finding an alternative to what you are currently doing by keeping your channels collection, or the type that contains it on your main GUI thread, while wrapping your .Update method into its own call (which potentially includes the adding of the item to the listbox upon updating?) within the type that contains the collection, rather than a call which is a member of the channel type itself, and try calling it like this:

```
        if (Application.Current != null){
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
            UpdateChannel(channel[j])));}
```

The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke allows for the thread communication to be sorted out by the Dispatcher when operating upon or calling things on your main GUI thread, from a background thread.